# Multiple NetBIOS names on Windows Server 2016

Tags: active-directory, netbios

Until at least Windows 2008R2 [it was possible to add multiple NetBIOS names](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/adding-multiple-netbios-names-for-windows-servers/) to the same machine, with each additional name resolveable via NetBIOS broadcasts (ie: the classical NetBIOS resolution, not involving DNS). It even was one of the [recommended approaches for file server consolidation.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/06/04/multiple-names-for-one-computer-consolidate-your-smb-file-servers-without-breaking-unc-paths/)

While on Windows Server 2016 you can still adding new NetBIOS names, it seems that the only resolveable name is the first (main) one. For example, taking a server with `MAINNAME` and `ALTNAME` as primary and secondary names, only `MAINNAME` is resolveable via the NetBIOS-specific broadcast method. `ALTNAME` is resolveable via DNS, and its records are added to the DNS server indeed.

So, I ask:

- do you know why the default behavior was changed?
- do you have any suggestions on how to make secondary NetBIOS names resolveable?

Comment: Why are you relying on NetBIOS for name resolution in 2018?

Comment: Because the server is installed in a domain-less environment. While I am introducing a domain now, this will require some time. In the meantime, I need NetBIOS name resolution to work.

Comment: you can use DNS without being in an Active Directory domain. Nothing in 2018 should require NetBIOS.

Comment: Yeah, and I did that. However, a legacy MS Access application tried the NetBIOS resolution first, slowing down the initial connection. I fixed it, however, this does not explain why and when Microsoft changed the default behavior described in the blog post I linked. Thanks anyway.